# Complex number calculations in Julia, weird result?

Tags: types, julia, linear-algebra

I was doing some simple linear algebra practice in Julia.

Here is how variables were defined

```
H = (1/sqrt(2)) * [1.0 + 0.0im 1.0 + 0.0im; 1.0 + 0.0im -1.0 + 0.0im;]
X = [0.0im 1.0 + 0.0im; 1.0 + 0.0im 0.0im;]
```

`H` computes to

```
 2×2 Array{Complex{Float64},2}:
 0.707107+0.0im   0.707107+0.0im
 0.707107+0.0im  -0.707107+0.0im
```

and `X` computes to

```
 2×2 Array{Complex{Float64},2}:
 0.0+0.0im  1.0+0.0im
 1.0+0.0im  0.0+0.0im
```

Identity matrix is defined as `I = [1.0 + 0.0im 0.0 + 0.0im; 0.0 + 0.0im 1.0 + 0.0im;]`

Now both `X * X` as well as `H * H` return

```
2×2 Array{Complex{Float64},2}:
1.0+0.0im  0.0+0.0im
0.0+0.0im  1.0+0.0im
```

As expected. But

```
I == X * X # returns true

I == H * H # returns false
```

`X * X - I` returns

```
 2×2 Array{Complex{Float64},2}:
 0.0+0.0im  0.0+0.0im
 0.0+0.0im  0.0+0.0im
```

as expected, while the same done with H gets

```
  2×2 Array{Complex{Float64},2}:
 -2.22045e-16+0.0im           0.0+0.0im
          0.0+0.0im  -2.22045e-16+0.0im
```

I am pretty new to Julia. Why is this happening?

Comment: Never compare floating point values with `==`, use `≈` (`isapprox`), which returns `true` for both your comparisons.

Comment: Julia also has `LinearAlgebra.I` representing an identity matrix of any size, in it's standard library.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `sqrt(2)` is a floating point number, such that `(sqrt(2)*sqrt(2))` does NOT equal 2.

One way to solve this problem is to define a new type for Algebraic numbers, as you can see in [AlgebracNumbers.jl](https://github.com/anj1/AlgebraicNumbers.jl).

Example:

```
sqrt(AlgebracNumber(2))^2 == 2
```

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that, unless you are doing something very special, the floating point "inexactness" is not something you need to worry about and using floating point numbers is sufficient, no need to reach for special number types like `AlgebracNumber`. Algorithms should not be sensitive to things like this, instead rewrite the code to use, for example` approximate comparisons instead of absolute comparisons etc.

Comment: As @fredrikekre pointed out, defining a new number type is not a efficient way to do numerical computations. `AlgebracNumber` should be used for symbolic tasks like doing linear algebra homeworks.